# Number of ways to choose $k$ subsets such that $ B_1 \cap B_2 \cap \cdot \cdot \cdot \cap B_k = \emptyset$.

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

Let $ \space n,k \in \mathbb Z \space $ such that $1 \le k \le n \space$. Let $\space A=\{1,2,...,n\}$. Find the number of ways to choose $k$ subsets $\space B_1,B_2,...,B_k\space $ of $A$ such that $ B_1 \cap B_2 \cap \cdot \cdot \cdot \cap B_k = \emptyset$.

Well, I did it using inclusion exclusion, but I'm wondering if this is possible using a **recursive formula**.

By inclusion exclusion: $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} (-1)^i (2^{n-i})^k$ and by binom $(2^k-1)^n$

Comment: Do the $k$ subsets have to be distinct?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes. the answer in closed form is $(2^k-1)^n$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I edited with 2 answers I got

Comment: That answer is for subsets that are not necessarily distinct.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, my bad. they are not necessarily distinct.

Comment: In any event, there is a direct counting argument for this particular answer. Let $P$ be the sets of subsets of $S=\{1,\dots,k\}$ other than all of $S$. Then if $F$ is the set of all functions from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to $P$, then $F$ is in one-to-one correspondence with the set you are counting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F(k,n)$ denote the answer you seek.

Note first that $F(k,1)=2^k-1$.  to see this, we remark that the only two subsets are $\emptyset, \{1\}$.  Thus in your list of $k$ we can choose freely from these two, but we can't choose $\{1\}$ every time.

Now consider $F(k,n)$.  If you delete the element $n$ from every set (if it is there) you get a selection counted by $F(k,n-1)$.  But starting from a selection of that form we can add $n$, or not, to each set, but we can't add it to every set.  Thus $$F(k,n)=F(k,n-1)\times (2^k-1)$$ and we are done.

Comment: Note that you have to ignore the condition that $k\leq n$, but that this is okay...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Didn't even see that condition.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, you could nominally start at $n=0$ to make the first step absolutely trivial :)

Comment: @RossMillikan  Right, thanks.  I'll edit.